# Iterate over list of tuples using a variable for the tail tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, tuples

How to iterate over `[(1,2,3), (2,3,1), (1,1,1)]` while splitting each tuple into a head and a tail?
I am searching concise an pythonic way like this:

```
for h, *t in [(1,2,3), (2,3,1), (1,1,1)]:
    # where I want t to be a tuple consisting of the last two elements
    val = some_fun(h)
    another_fun(val, t)
```

The above doesn't work for python 2.7.

Comment: Try surrounding `h, *t` with parenthesis, .e., `(h, *t)`

Comment: @dcg That won't work either. Python 2 doesn't support this kind of unpacking as far as I know.

Comment: `The above doesn't work for python 2.7` WOW. Learned something new here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `map` to and list slicing:

```
for h, t in map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1:]), [(1,2,3), (2,3,1), (1,1,1)]):
    print("h = %s, t=%s"%(h, t))
#h = 1, t=(2, 3)
#h = 2, t=(3, 1)
#h = 1, t=(1, 1)
```